# How do I change the bar colors on Ant Design Chart

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am implementing this chart using antd chart:
https://charts.ant.design/en/examples/column/percent#basic.
I need to change the colors. How do I change each of the 3 colors within the bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy, just add a `color` configuration -

```
color: ['#d62728', '#2ca02c', '#000000'],
```

You can add as many colors. Order is preserved from top to bottom. A single color would mean all stacks would have the same color. You can also return a function with additional logic -

```
color: ({ type }) => {
    if(type === 'some condition'){
      return '#2ca02c';
    }
    return '#d62728';
  }
```

Comment: Do you know how to have some custom fields in this function?